# How to Instantiate Game

Tags: java, game-engine

I see this piece of code in almost every game example for Java. Create an instance of the `Game` class then execute the loop from that instance.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Game g = new Game();
    g.gameLoop();
}

public Game () {
}
```

However, as I don't do anything apart from the execution of the `gameLoop()` why not write it like this? I don't *really* need to store the instance of `Game` anywhere do I? Like this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Game ();
}

public Game () {
    gameLoop();
}
```

If so for what?

Both cases are working and have been tested by me.

Comment: A Constructor is used for creating a valid instance of a class and nothing else. Writing `gameLoop();` in the Constructor might work, but it is very bad code.

Comment: @Tom I figure that is the answer I am looking for then.

Comment: You could just do `new Game().gameLoop();`. This won't break any conventions of OOP.

Comment: As @Tom said, it's basically a matter of semantics and clean code. Code is easier to understand when every method either _instantiaties_ something, _returns_ something or _does_ something, but not two or the three things in the same method.

Comment: Why not make `gameLoop` static and invoke it in `main()`?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch `Game` contains a lot of variables, other methods as well. That would force me to build most of the engine as `static`.

Comment: @Emz It's effectively the same as putting the `gameLoop` in the constructor. As you said you keep no references to the engine anyway.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch when you put it that way I see how mad my question actually was! Cheers for the metaphor!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**if you write it like this:**

```
new Game ();
```

This is done by using a constructor. A constructor's main purpose is to create objects and initialize any variables and set any initial value you need to set.

If you only write `new Game()`, it can compile, but doesn't mean it is a good way to implement. Why is it not a good implementation?

It is because doing so, you are as good as writing your `entire game` within the constructor. It is wrong to begin with, because you are actually not supposed to implement your entire logic in the constructor.

So why people do it as such:

```
Game g = new Game();
g.gameLoop();
```

Now, note the difference of this and the one you suggested (using a constructor). Doing so you **modularize** your codes into sub-problems. Benefit of modularization? Lots of it:

- Easier to manage your codes
- Easier to debug your codes, shorter debugging time
- Write once, use it `n` times
- Easier to read and maintain your codes

---

However, there are different ways you code with Java. It is also possible to make your `gameLoop()` **static**. So that you can do this (without instantiating an object):

```
Game.gameLoop();
```

This is possible, but I don't advise you doing this.

Comment: I know why you want to do it in other cases. I was just curious of this particular case.

Answer (score 0):

One reason is because of philosophy: constructors are for constructing things, not running them.  But there is a practical concern as well.  If you call `gameLoop()` inside of the constructor, then you have no way of creating a `Game` without running it.  This could pose a problem if, say, you wanted to construct a game, then make some changes to its configuration, then run it.  This scenario would make even more sense if you ended up subclassing `Game`.